# Wicket 1.4 EJB Support

Tags: wicket, ejb-3.0, glassfish-3, wicket-1.4

I tried implementing the JavaEE Inject jar from Wicket Stuff. (glassfish v3, wicket 1.4)
 - however, the code given in the tutorial doesn't work

> method
>   addComponentInstantiationListener in
>   class org.apache.wicket.Application
>   cannot be applied to given types
>   required:
>   org.apache.wicket.application.IComponentInstantiationListener
>   found:
>   org.wicketstuff.javaee.injection.JavaEEComponentInjector

looks to me like the API has changed. The JIRA link inside

http://wicketstuff.org/confluence/display/STUFFWIKI/JavaEE+Inject

and the Repository link are both broken. Is it still maintained?

Another short question: Is it possible to populate ListView directly with entity beans? I'd like to avoid too many proxy classes.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can inject a ListView with entity beans.  You should do so by creating an implementation of IDataProvider (or one of it's sub-interfaces) for the iterator and have it wrap the entities with LoadableDetachableModel so they can be reloaded instead of serialized as a part of the session.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out: I didn't expect there to be a difference between 1.4.13 and 1.4.14 but apparently the API changed there significantly.